# Gitlab Runner Calling before_script on server OS not Docker Image

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I just set up a GitLab runner and tried running a job but it failed and the error returned was

```
$ apt-get update -yqq
bash: line 92: apt-get: command not found
```

my `.gitlab.yml` looks like so:

```
image: ubuntu:latest

cache:
  paths:
  - vendor/

before_script:
- apt-get update -yqq
- docker-php-ext-install mbstring mcrypt pdo_pgsql curl json intl gd xml zip bz2 opcache

stages:
  - test

# We test PHP7 with MySQL, but we allow it to fail
test:
  script:
  - ./vendor/bin/phpunit
  allow_failure: false
```

The strange thing is that the server I am running on is a Redhat server and when I change the update command to `yum update` it seems to work.

Comment: Which [executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/) do you use ?

Comment: @NicolasPepinster Shell executor

Comment: could you try using `Docker executor` instead ?

Comment: @NicolasPepinster tried it. It works fine. Thank you!

Comment: I put it on answer, please approve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [configure](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html) your runner to use `Docker executor` to be able to use `image` keyword in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`